# Which Video Player for my website? (ie6, cross-browser compatible)

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, internet-explorer-6, video-streaming

So! My question is pretty straight forward, I have a website (Build in ASP.NET 2.0) which uses an old video player to play the videos (FLplayer progressive) the problem is all the videos on the site got converted to .mp4 (For better quality) but this old player won't play them... Which would be a nice player for the site that works on ie6 that would play the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but this old player won't play them

The supported video file type(s) are usually not down to the Flash video player product used, but the version of the Flash plugin itself. Support for H.264 MPEG4 came in Flash 10, I think. Are you sure you are testing this with an up-to-date Flash plugin?

Comment: Would changing the line http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0 to http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0. Fix the problem? If not how can update the plug-in itself?

Comment: @Gotjosh I don't know, I'm not familiar with how to force a Flash movie to insist on a certain version. It could well be the way you write, though. Try it out.

Comment: Ii just tried another flash player and it worked :-). In case you're wondering its flowplayer.org, thanks!