# Which player has largest browser support?

Tags: cross-browser, media-player

We're having issues with users who are not able to play audio & video on our site. Up to date (I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388237/which-video-player-for-my-website-ie6-cross-browser-compatible), but it isn't very helpful) - which is the best choice for a player to work for most users? (PC browsers - specifically IE8+, Firefox & Chrome. Mobile browsers, iPhones, Android based systems etc.)

Thoughts have taken us to HTML5, embedded flash player, automatic download (not an option we liked). Silverlight is the one we're having problems with now.

Glad to hear insights on this!

**Edit:** Seems having wmv files sort of gets in the way... Any solution for that?

Comment: Have you evaluated http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/ - JWPlayer? I've used this and it works great on iPads, iPhones, most modern browsers too.

Comment: @Asif If I'd receive answers which pin the question - I'd accept. I admit there was one I overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to JWPlayer, I've used http://videojs.com/ several times and it works well.

Comment: Would you know to compare them?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used JWPlayer since it was Flash only.